# External Text Editor in Gnome 3

Tags: gnome3

Is there any way to invoke a text editor to edit the contents of a text area in Gnome 3? Something like the old "It's All Text" Firefox extension for the entire Gnome 3 desktop?

So far all I've found are tips for using an external editor in Evolution.